# How to define route parameters in Router.js depends on Urls in Nuxt Js?

Tags: vue.js, routes, nuxt.js, vue-router, vue-composition-api

I use Nuxt composition api in my project. I have 1 detail page and 2 different url comes from my API. I don't want to create different detail pages for every url. I use extendRoutes in my project and I need to solve this issue.

**urls**

```
/sport/asian-football-3581.  -> sub category + news title
/video/world/mama-dog-rubble-in-india-3581246. -> category + subcategory + news title
```

**router.js**

```
 extendRoutes(routes, resolve) {
    routes.push(

   {
        name: 'detail',
        path: '/:subCategory/:title(.*)-:id([0-9]+)',
        component: resolve('pages/detail.vue'),
      },

 path: '/:subCategory/:title(.*)-:id([0-9]+)',                                         
 path: '/:category/:subCategory/:title(.*)-:id([0-9]+)',
```

Paths can come with these two types. I want to route them to same detail page.
And I need to catch subCategory, title, id and if it has category params also. In my solution, if second path comes, I cant catch parameters true

Answer (score 0):

**I found answer**

```
        path: '/:category/:subCategory?/:title(.*)-:id([0-9]+)',
```

this solves my problem